# Oxygen Builder with theme in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using [Oxygen Builder](https://oxygenbuilder.com/) to recreate the home page of a WordPress site that uses a premium theme. I now came to know that oxygen builder bypasses themes. as a result, no other pages are able to use the theme to render. If I deactivate oxygen builder rest of the website works fine but the homepage built with oxygen builder does not (for obvious reasons). Can someone please suggest me a way or a workaround to use both oxygen builder and the theme at together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acctually Oxygen is Designed to eliminates the need for WordPress themes. This Means you can not Edit Wordpress Theme with Oxygen, Because Oxygen Forcefully Replaces the WP-Theme From the Run.
It Seems Funny But, By Using Oxygen, Actually you are Ignoring WP-Themes :D :D :D.

So that In this case you must create a Oxygen template for your site From the “Admin -> Oxygen Menu”. When you design It inherit the Oxygen template you made From “Admin -> Oxygen Menu”.

Now You Have two Option...
1. Create Desired template in Oxygen then Edit.
2. Try this Free Version of wp-Theme Editor to Edit Themes as Well, And then Go for Pro
I will Suggest ... Elementor Free. Link is Given Below
https://wordpress.org/plugins/elementor/

Answer (score 0):

That only way I found around this is to use a plugin that activates/deactivates plugins on the go, depending upon the Page/Post you are on, Which is really untidy. I would suggest anyone in the same position to either **create a template using Oxygen or drop the idea of using Oxygen.**

Answer (score 0):

There's long been a plugin by Sridhar Katakam, **Oxygen Theme Enabler**, to use the active template alongside Oxygen. Info and Download on Github:

https://github.com/srikat/oxygenthemeenabler

[image: Screenshot of Oxygen Theme Enabler]